# nbconvert 6: How to customize Latex template

Tags: python, jupyter, nbconvert

I'm trying to create a nbconvert (6.x) template that slightly modifies the default latex template.

I created a "no_header" template in `<userprofile>\Miniconda3\share\jupyter\nbconvert\templates\no_header`:

```
.
+-- no_header
|   +-- conf.json
|   +-- no_header.tex.j2
```

The conf.json contains:

```json
{
    "base_template": "latex",
    "mimetypes": {
        "text/latex": true,
        "text/tex": true,
        "application/pdf": true
    }
}
```

The `no_header.tex.j2` contains:

```
((*- extends 'latex' -*))

((*- block packages -*))
asdf
((* endblock packages *))
```

I took the block name `packages` from the `style_jupyter.tex.j2`. This section contains some usepackage commands.

I then created a simple notebook and tried using the template to convert it to tex via the command:

`jupyter nbconvert --to=latex --template=no_header my_nb.ipynb`

The command successfully creates the tex output - But it does not seem to use the template. The output is the exact same if I omit the template parameter to the cli call. Also, the string `asdf` is not present in the generated file, further indicating that the template was not activated.

When running the above command with `--debug`, the no_header template is listed under the 'template paths' listing. Also, when I misspelled the template name I got an error, so I think the call does find the template, but somehow does not use it.

What I tried so far:

- All the tutorials online only describe the old template format (single files)
- The documentation of nbconvert does not contain an mwe
- For the approach described above, I followed [this](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1558) github issue.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Did you find a way to tweak the LaTeX template? I would like to make the tabular environment font smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The conf.json file is fine, but I think you need to call your entrypoint index.tex.j2. The name of the template is defined by the directory, not the .j2 file name.

Then in your no_header/index.tex.j2, you then specify which template you want to inherit from, e.g. borrowing from the standard latex article you start like this:

```
((=- Default to the notebook output style -=))
((*- if not cell_style is defined -*))
    ((* set cell_style = 'style_jupyter.tex.j2' *))
((*- endif -*))

((=- Inherit from the specified cell style. -=))
((* extends cell_style *))

((*- block docclass -*))
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
((*- endblock docclass -*))
```

and to customize the packages section, you then add as in the question:

```
((*- block packages -*))
asdf
((* endblock packages *))
```

Presumably you'll want to put a lot more in the "packages" block. If you want to add to certain blocks rather than override, include a super() call.

The default latex template directory has a number of files which add quite a lot of latex commands; you can track the inheritance chain (in the above example starting from style_jupyter.tex.j2) to see what all the different blocks are called so you can tweak them as needed (e.g. "margins").

Comment: Does this work?

Comment: it does for me (nbconvert version 6.3.0). The point is that the directory name determines the template name, your content needs to go into a file called index.tex.j2 and the conf.json file should be as suggested in the question. You don't need other files in your custom template directory.